# Error for Associative Array : Missing IN OUT Parameter

Tags: arrays, oracle, collections, associative

I'm learning about Collections and trying out Associative Arrays in Oracle 11g. I'm using SQL Developer to write and test my code below and I am getting the error which I can't troubleshoot :

```
Error Report
Missing IN OUT Parameter at index ::1
```

Code I have written is as follows:

```
---SIMPLE collections EXAMPLE

DECLARE

  TYPE prospect_towns IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (25)
    INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

a_big_towns prospect_towns;  -- associative array
i PLS_INTEGER := 1;        -- index for the array

v_counter NUMBER;

v_town VARCHAR2(25);

BEGIN

    a_big_towns(1):='Birmingham';
    a_big_towns(2):='London':
    a_big_towns(3):='Manchester';

   -- v_counter := 1;


    FOR i IN 1..a_big_towns.COUNT
    LOOP <<big towns>>

    --v_town := a_big_towns(i);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inside Loop, town is '||a_big_towns(i));


    i= a_big_towns.next:



    END LOOP<<big towns>>
END;
/
```

Any ideas what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second of these lines:

```
a_big_towns(1):='Birmingham';
a_big_towns(2):='London':
a_big_towns(3):='Manchester';
```

... has a colon at the end, instead of a semicolon. That's causing the following `a_big_towns` to be interpreted as a bind variable name by the parser. So it should be:

```
a_big_towns(2):='London';
```

Once you get past that, this line isn't needed, and would need `:=` instead of `=` if it was, and also has a colon instead of a semicolon at the end:

```
i= a_big_towns.next:
```

... so remove that completely.

I'm not sure the labels are really adding anything here, but if you do have a label it doesn't need to be repeated at the end, and the name can't have a space in it, so make it:

```
<<big_towns>>
FOR i IN 1..a_big_towns.COUNT LOOP
```

And this needs a semicolon at the dned:

```
END LOOP;
```

[This SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/31886) compiles.

Comment: Alex Thank you very much, I don't know how many hours I spent yesterday trying to figure out what was wrong. Thanks for pointing out the other mistakes too. Regarding the label, this code was part of a bigger program I had written with a nested loop, I had put the label to keep track of which Loop ends where. I simplified to troubleshoot my error. The program worked after I corrected the mistakes you pointed out.